# Using this[] keyword to retrive a value from a class instant

Tags: c#, class, this, instant

In the following example this[] is used within a class to obtain a value from somewhere from the class instant. Where is this value stored? Is it likely the [] operator being overloaded or is this just c# syntax I am unfamiliar with?

```
public class MyUserSettings : ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    [UserScopedSetting()]
    [DefaultSettingValue("white")]
    public Color BackgroundColor
    {
        get
        {
            return ((Color)this["BackgroundColor"]);
        }
        set
        {
            this["BackgroundColor"] = (Color)value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is called the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx).  It is very similar to overloading operators for a class.  Somewhere else in that class, or in one of that classes base classes, an indexer is defined.

Answer (score 4):

It is the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx) syntax.

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take parameters.

One of the classes that `MyUserSettings` inherits from has implemented a `string` indexer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is an overloaded [index operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste.aspx).